# fingerprint Putty

Tags: putty

Is there a way to force Putty to display the fingerprint on the very first connection of a Key as SHA-256 ? I know that Bitvise SSH Client is displaying the Host Key Fingerprint in 3 different ways:

- MD5
- Bubble-Babble
- SHA-256

Answer (score 1):

Display of the host key seems to be hard coded as an MD5 fingerprint.

In putty source, the `do_ssh1_login` function in the ssh.c file logs the host key fingerprint by calling the function `rsa_fingerprint`.  The `rsa_fingerprint` function in sshrsa.c is hard coded to return MD5 fingerprints.